# Panel and launcher disappeared after using ccsm and resetting to defaults

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, ccsm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. Last time I just installed Compiz and `ccsm` from the Software Centre. After I opened it, I made some common changes and then reset to defaults. But then my complete panel (as well as my dock) had disappeared, and after rebooting it was still gone. I also tried deleting the .config file for Compiz, and using commands to restore GNOME.